# Database access slow after upgrade from Server 2003 to 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

In our work Environment before we used Window 2003 server OS , in which we mapped network drive to process database operation.

Now we have upgraded Operating system to Window Server 2008(R2), now in this OS when we mapped network drive to process database operation compare to window 2003 server ,it takes more time(> 1 hour).

However if it local drive there is no problem..but why it slow down process using network drives ?

Please share , if there is any idea why it slow at map drive ?

Comment: I'm assuming that because there is no in-place upgrade path for a Windows Server 2003 to 2008 R2 upgrade, you've also replaced hardware.  Can you tell us what hardware you migrated to?  What kind of interconnect you are using for your networking?

Answer (score 3):

Running databases off a network drive is a really dumb idea. I'm surprised it seemed to work tolerably on the old architecture (although from you're description you've only quoted the difference in time taken for an operation - there's a big difference between a 1 second operations taking more than 1 hour + 1 sec, and between an operation taking 24 and 25 hours).

Stop trying to fix the wrong problem.

Comment: With the exception of using a terminal services and/or Citrix environment, some vendors REQUIRE their older database systems to be used in this manor.  Granted the person asking the question seems to be a little out-of-touch with the best way to handle this situation, it could be that he/she has no alternative than to run his database application across a network drive.